# Finding tweets containg a keyword in R and updating

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, twitter

Im using R in order to find words in strings that way i can categorize them in 2 columns. Im using grep to find all of the rows where the keyword exists, but im having trouble writing a loop to update another column with a value of 1 if the keyword exists in the string. Tweet.Text is the column name containing the strings, @casekeenum7 is the keyword im looking for and Keenum is the column that I would like to update with a value of 1 for each row that contains the keyword.

Code:

```
for (i in 1:length(Tweet.Text)){
  if(grep('@casekeenum',Tweet.Text[i])){
    Keenum[i]==1
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error in if (grep("@casekeenum7", Tweet.Text[i])) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Comment: `grep` returns a numeric index.  Probably you need `grepl`  BTW, you may not need a `for` loop i.e. `as.integer(grepl('@casekeenum', Tweet.Text))` returns binary values if we need to only change values for TRUE, then `Tweet.Text[grepl('@casekeenum', Tweet.Text)] <- 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a for loop:

```
df = data.frame(Tweet.Text=c("Hello","@casekeenum"),
                Keenum=c(0,0))


df$Keenum[grepl("@casekeenum",df$Tweet.Text)]=1
```

returns:

```
   Tweet.Text Keenum
1       Hello      0
2 @casekeenum      1
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked. 1 add on question quick. How would I check by 2 keywords. @casekeenum and #casekeenum?

Comment: You can use the `|` operator (or simply create two lines). Example: `df$Keenum[grepl("@casekeenum|#casekeenum",df$Tweet.Text)]=1`